# Is it valid to bid on a cargo with zero coins?

Tags: cargo-noir

In *Cargo Noir*, when one sends ships to the ports to bid on the cargo there, is it valid to bid zero coins?  The wording of the rules in various places seems to expect that at least one coin is always there, but we couldn't find anything that flat-out says so.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've added the [tag:cargo-noir] tag for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried to do that, but my numbers are still too small.  ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a zero coin bid is not valid. This was [asked on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/627117/bidding-0-on-ports), and the clarification "no you cannot" is from [Eric Hautemont](http://boardgamegeek.com/user/Erich), one of the game designers at Days of Wonder (who produced the game).

Comment: Just as I suspected, but good to have confirmation.